# Nextjs - how to apply styled-jsx to jsx returned from method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Using Nextjs with styled-jsx I have written the component below.

Now I would like to know how to apply styled-jsx to the jsx that is being returned from the `getLinks` method.

In the below example the jsx coming from the `getLinks` method are not being styled.

```
class MainHeader extends Component {
  getLinks = () => {
    const links = linkData.map(link => (
      <Link key={link.path} href={link.path}>
        <a className="link">{link.title}</a>
      </Link>
    ));
    return links;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mainContainer">
        {this.getLinks()}
        <style jsx>
          {`
            .mainContainer {
              background: ${colors.pri};
              display: flex;
              height: 60px;
            }

            .link {
              color: ${colors.tPri};
              font-size: 2rem;
              margin-left: 1.6rem;
            }
          `}
        </style>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I know I could do it like I have done in the code below, but I'd rather have my render method a bit more clean.

```
lass MainHeader extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mainContainer">
        {linkData.map(link => (
          <Link key={link.path} href={link.path}>
            <a className="link">{link.title}</a>
          </Link>
        ))}
        <style jsx>
          {`
            .mainContainer {
              align-items: center;
              background: ${colors.pri};
              display: flex;
              height: 60px;
            }

            .link {
              color: ${colors.tPri};
              font-size: 2rem;
              margin-left: 1.6rem;
              text-decoration: none;
            }
          `}
        </style>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the author of styled-jsx here :)

You have two options. The first being moving the `.link` styles to where they belong (the `getLinks` method):

```
getLinks = () => {
  const links = linkData.map(link => (
    <>
      <Link key={link.path} href={link.path}>
        <a className="link">{link.title}</a>
      </Link>
      <style jsx>{`
        .link {
          color: ${colors.tPriD};
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  ));
  return links;
}
```

Don't worry about the loop, styled-jsx will dedupe them and render the styles only once.

The second option is using a newer feature that is `css.resolve`:

```
getLinks = (scopedClass) => {
  const links = linkData.map(link => (
    <Link key={link.path} href={link.path}>
      <a className={`${scopedClass} link`}>{link.title}</a>
    </Link>
  ));
  return links;
}

render() {
  const { className, styles } = css.resolve`
    .link {
      color: ${colors.tPri};
      font-size: 2rem;
      margin-left: 1.6rem;
    }
  `

  return (
    <div className="mainContainer">
      {styles}
      {this.getLinks(className)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you are **not** using props in the styles I recommend you to move them outside of the component as it will perform better.

Hope this helps.

FWIW we have a community on Spectrum for styled-jsx https://spectrum.chat/styled-jsx

Comment: Thanks, the your solution works. Although there are some cases when it seems to result in an error. I have posted a question about that on the spectrum.chat community: https://spectrum.chat/styled-jsx/general/adding-style-jsx-to-react-component-method-gives-error-react-children-only-expected-to-receive-a-single-react-element-child~e6418e9b-264b-4564-9107-a9be1978a9a9

Comment: Ah yep, I think that this because `Link` accepts only one child. Updated the answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will be clean enough for you

```
class MainHeader extends Component {
  getLinks = () => {
    const links = linkData.map(link => (
      <Link key={link.path} href={link.path}>
        <a className="link">{link.title}</a>
      </Link>
    ));
    return <>
            {links}
              <style jsx>
          {`
            .link {
              color: ${colors.tPri};
              font-size: 2rem;
              margin-left: 1.6rem;
            }
          `}
        </style>
           </>;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mainContainer">
        {this.getLinks()}
        <style jsx>
          {`
            .mainContainer {
              background: ${colors.pri};
              display: flex;
              height: 60px;
            }
          `}
        </style>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Using your code, my links don't receive any styling. Are you sure this should work?

Comment: I did a simple [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/717r0py5q6) for you without all the data in your app. It should work.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but for some reason the styling is not applied when using your code. I copied and pasted, also seeing  0 1 2 3 4 rendered instead of my own link data, but it is styled with default styling, not as specified in the accompanying styling. I guess it;s a separate question in of itself as to why I am not getting expected output.